# Error: Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, http-status-code-404, content-security-policy

I have a React + Node.js app that works fine on localhost but runs into errors when deployed to Heroku, resulting in a 404 response status.

This is one of the console errors I get when loading the app on Chrome:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
(anonymous) @ 1:3

...      
 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

These scripts and stylesheets are not directly referenced anywhere in my code.

I am trying all of the following code regarding Content Security Policy:

public/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src-elem 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline'" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://www.pagespeed-mod.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src-elem 'self' https://www.pagespeed-mod.com 'unsafe-inline'" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; style-src-elem 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'" />
    ...
  </head>
</html>
```

src/App.tsx:

```
return (
    <div className="h-screen flex flex-col">
      <Helmet>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src-elem 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline'" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://www.pagespeed-mod.com 'unsafe-inline'; script-src-elem 'self' https://www.pagespeed-mod.com 'unsafe-inline'" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; style-src-elem 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'" />
      </Helmet>
    ...
```

src/server/index.js:

```
const scriptSources = ["'self'", 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com', 'https://www.pagespeed-mod.com']
const styleSources = ["'self'", 'https://fonts.googleapis.com']
app.use(
  helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
      scriptSrc: scriptSources,
      styleSrc: styleSources,
    },
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Content-Security-Policy (CSP) script-src directive specifies valid sources for JavaScript. This includes not only URLs loaded directly into  elements.

The error is due to the CSP header for script-src is set to self so if you add inline script with any src other than your domain scripts it voilates CSP policy, so you have to add it in the allowed list.

I have not worked woth heroku but check you have to set the CSP configuration anywhere there eg :
CSP Header : script-src 'self' [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) ...;
else if you are using CSP in Node js with helmet or anything add the analytics url in whitelist of the script src.

```
const scriptSources = ["'self'",'www.google-analytics.com'...]    
app.use(
   helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
      directives: {
         ....
         scriptSrc: scriptSources,
         // ...
        },
        })
     )
```

For more info go through this [Mozila CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src)

Comment: I added this at the bottom of my index.js file (which is run in Heroku), but I still get the same errors. Am I doing this correctly, or should I modify my front-end React code to configure the content security policy (HTML meta tags)?

Comment: try adding in meta tag <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com">
let the ssl have proper schema too https://.............

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same errors. I have edited the post to show my changes.

Comment: default-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com 'unsafe-inline' try adding these in default src and add the SSL one too and check if it works you can look into https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/web/csp   which provides better security

Comment: I did that and changed `script-src` to `script-src-elem` (as stated in the console error), but it still says that `script-src-elem` was not explicitly set.

Comment: Is your website publically available if so can you share the URL ,so we can debug better

Comment: [Here](https://wordle-with-score-database.herokuapp.com/) is my website deployment. (Errors are in the console)

Comment: getting this error (GET https://wordle-with-score-database.herokuapp.com/ 404 (Not Found)

Comment: keep the CSP at only one place and in FE on node , if still you are getting default-src none then you have to check from where this issue is from either heroku or in code if you have anywhere , check if this helps :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57454623/getting-a-violates-the-following-content-security-policy-directive-default-sr

Comment: How should I modify my CSP? I do not see an explicit "default-src 'none'" anywhere in my code. ([This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72130352/where-does-heroku-create-the-build-folder-getting-404-status-error) shows my server filepath.)

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple CSPs, your content need to pass *all* policies. It seems like the initial problem is a very restrictive policy setting "default-src 'none'". Everything is blocked due to this policy, and adding new policies won't help. You will need to identify where and how this policy is set and then modify or disable it to allow whatever is needed.